# Setting initial value in select/dropdown with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, default-value, selectlist

This has been driving me crazy as I'm sure it's simple, but I've tried a multitude of different approaches over the last 2 days and nothing worked properly.

I have two select-dropdowns in my view HTML:

```
 <p>Spend between

<select
    id        ='minSpend' 
    ng-model  ="cheapest"
    ng-options="offer.PriceAUD as '$'+Math.round(offer.PriceAUD) for offer in offers |  uniquePrice:'PriceAUD'">      
</select>
and
<select 
    id        ='maxSpend'
    ng-model  ="dearest"
    ng-options="offer.PriceAUD as '$'+Math.round(offer.PriceAUD) for offer in offers |  uniquePrice:'PriceAUD'"         >
</select>
```

They populate nicely with unique values once data is received.
The uniquePrice filter looks like this:

```
app.filter('uniquePrice', function() {
return function(input, key) {
    if (typeof input == 'undefined'){return;}

    var unique = {};
    var uniqueList = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
            unique[input[i][key]] = "";
            input[i][key] = Math.round(input[i][key]);
            uniqueList.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
 };
});
```

What I like is the lowest price and highest price to be selected initially. I managed to write a fn that does it "on-click":

```
         $scope.setValues = function(){ 
             $scope.cheapest    = $scope.offers[0].PriceAUD;
             $scope.dearest     = $scope.offers[ $scope.offers.length-1].PriceAUD; 

         }
```

[ $scope.offers comes from the DB sorted by PriceAUD ASC ]

Triggered in the HTML by a simple:

```
 <button ng-click="setValues()">Set Values</button>
```

Which works fine. But how can I trigger this when data-loading is complete? I tried:

```
        $scope.offers  = Items.query();


        $scope.offers.$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.setValues();     
        });
```

But it doesn't work.
And when I set $scope.dearest = $scope.offers[0].PriceAUD in the controller directly it doesn't work because the promise isn't resolved. I'm sure I just need to put this in the right place, but where?
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** The code to get Items:

```
 var appServices = angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource']);

 appServices.factory('Items', ['$resource',

function($resource){ 
  var url = '/api/get/offers.json';
  var paramDefaults = {};
  var actions = "{      query: {method:'GET', params:{id:'Items'}, isArray:true}";
  var optns = '';

  return $resource(url, paramDefaults, actions , optns); 
 }]);
```

Comment: what  `Items.query()` returns ? can you paste `Items.query` function code

Comment: @levi: I added the code to the question. It just returns a normal JSON array. Thanks

Comment: are u sure that `$resource(url, paramDefaults, actions , optns);` returns a normal JSON array ?

Comment: Items.query should return a promise and then you can do `.then`